# Error comparing strings in assembly language: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000043

Tags: x86, inline-assembly

The code is supposed to compare an inputted string with various hardcoded options to provide a menu.

This is the code I'm using

```
.stack 4096
 ...
    GetStdHandle proto :dword
    ReadConsoleA  proto :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword
    WriteConsoleA proto :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword
    STD_INPUT_HANDLE equ -10
 ...
.data
 ...
    bufSize = 80
    inputHandle DWORD ?
    buffer db bufSize dup(?)    
    choice DWORD ?
    letterC DWORD "C"
 ...
.code
 ...
    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    mov inputHandle, eax
    invoke ReadConsoleA, inputHandle, addr buffer, bufSize, addr choice,0
    mov ESI, choice
    mov EDI, letterC
    CLD            
    MOV ECX,10        
    REPE CMPSB        
 ...
```

It always gives me an error in the last line `REPE CMPSB`:

> Exception thrown at 0x00F6195F in Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000043.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you set both the source and the destination register to wrong values.
I'm gonna explain that:

The function [`ReadConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) has the following signature:

```
BOOL WINAPI ReadConsole(
  _In_     HANDLE  hConsoleInput,
  _Out_    LPVOID  lpBuffer,
  _In_     DWORD   nNumberOfCharsToRead,
  _Out_    LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsRead,
  _In_opt_ LPVOID  pInputControl
);
```

With

```
mov ESI, choice
```

you are copying your fourth parameter of `ReadConsole`, `choice`, to `ESI`.
`choice` contains the `NumberOfCharsRead`, so it is no memory pointer, but rather a **length value**. This doesn't work.

With

```
mov EDI, letterC
```

you move **the value** of `letterC` to `EDI` rather than its address. To get the address to `EDI`, you'd have to use

```
mov EDI, OFFSET letterC
```

This error becomes obvious in your error message which reads

> Access violation reading location 0x00000043.

The value of `0x00000043` equals to the ASCII char value of the character `C`, 0x43. To get its address - which would be correct - you can use the `LEA` instruction like `lea EDI, letterC` or the `OFFSET` directive which is more efficient. Reading or writing to a value as address will almost always result in an error.

---

To make it right, take into consideration the following approach:

```
invoke ReadConsoleA, inputHandle, addr buffer, bufSize, addr choice,0
CLD            
MOV  ESI, OFFSET buffer   ; address of buffer is source
MOV  EDI, OFFSET letterC  ; address of letterC is destination
MOV  ECX, choice          ; length of string is choice (bytes read)
REPE CMPSB                ; execute
```

This solution is better, but it contains a major error: `REPE CMPSB` compares characters and continues comparing them as long as they're equal. But your `letterC` is only one character long, so you will get an overflow after passing the `C` character - the second iteration.

---

Your question is unclear on what you really expect, so the following is a mere speculation:
A possible alternative would be using `REPNE SCASB` with the character `letterC` in `AL` (`MOV AL, letterC`) which would search for the first occurrence of `C`:

```
invoke ReadConsoleA, inputHandle, addr buffer, bufSize, addr choice,0
CLD            
MOV   EDI, OFFSET buffer  ; address of buffer is search source
MOV   EAX, letterC        ; value of letterC
MOV   ECX, choice         ; length of string is choice (bytes read)
REPNE SCASB               ; execute
```

Comment: Yes this works thanks. I changed `MOV AL, letterC` to `MOV EAX, letterC` and `SCASB` to `SCASW` because I got this error: "error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size"

Comment: Yes. I fixed the `MOV EAX, letterC` in the answer. But you probably should use `SCASB` for BYTE size, because you use the `ReadConsoleA` ANSI version with 1 byte width and not the 16-bit UniCode version `ReadConsoleW` with 2 byte width. Otherwise you'd read BYTEs and scan for WORDs which would make your code pretty dysfunctional.

Comment: I tired to use a `jnz` to check if a match is found but it seems to be jumping whatever I input is `jnz` not the correct command to use?

Comment: Try to compare `ECX` to `0` as an alternative. So if `TEST ECX, ECX` sets the `ZERO` flag, there was no match. [Here (see the example below) is an example of checking the flag directly](http://www.ousob.com/ng/asm/ng1a8af.php).

Comment: Actually using `scasb` instead of `scasw` fixed it oops

Comment: You don't "have to" (and shouldn't) use `lea EDI, letterC`.  Use `mov EDI, OFFSET letterC` because it's shorter and more efficient, with no downsides in 32-bit code.  Only use LEA for a bare symbol in 64-bit mode for RIP-relative addressing.